# Error in ewa.js when trying to activate new worksheet in excel online

Tags: javascript, excel, office365, office-js

I'm trying to create a new worksheet and put values in cells in a js add-in in office online.
Here's my sample code (based off examples in API docs - https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/worksheetcollection):

```
return Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var worksheet;
    return Promise.resolve('mySheetName')
        .then(function (sheetName) {
            dtSheetName = sheetName;
            worksheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.add(dtSheetName);
            worksheet.load('name');
            worksheet.activate();
            console.log("Finished adding worksheet");
        })
        .then(ctx.sync) // Error in this ctx.sync
        .then(function () {
            aCell = worksheet.getCell(0, 0);
```

I've also tried variants on this (e.g. trying to sync context after adding the sheet)

```
return Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var worksheet;
    return Promise.resolve('mySheetName')
        .then(function (sheetName) {
            dtSheetName = sheetName;
            worksheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.add(dtSheetName);
            console.log("Finished adding worksheet");
        })
        .then(ctx.sync)
        .then(function () {
            worksheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(dtSheetName);
            worksheet.activate();
            worksheet.load('name');
            console.log("Finished activating sheet");
        })
        .then(ctx.sync) // Error in this ctx.sync
        .then(function () {
            stagingTableCell = worksheet.getCell(0, 0);
```

But in all cases, Excel online will just hang saying 'Working' in the bottom left corner.  If I open the debugger console and catch uncaught exceptions, there's an error in ewa.js:

`throw Error.argument("name", "No item exists with the name '" + n + "'.");`

Where `n = "mySheetName"`

Has anybody experienced this issue before? Any suggestions for a fix?  In general, when do we need to call sync() ?

Comment: But do you actually see the sheet being added?   And is the name as you expect it?

Comment: Also, FWIW, I don't think it's "EWA.js", is it?  It's just an Office Add-in.  I recommend renaming the title of the question, just to avoid confusion with the actual EWA.js, circa 5 years ago (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee589063.aspx)

Comment: Hi Michael, It does add a sheet, but the sheet is blank (ie, the grid isn't drawn -- if I force refresh the page, it will show the grid - but the remaining add-in code won't run).  The exception is indeed in a js file called Ewa.js (not sure if that's related to the link you provided) -- ie, it is not code that I wrote (add-in code) that throws the exception.  It is somewhere in office.js internals.

Comment: Ewa.js is a giant minified file (unminified it is 49,481 lines long)  It's served from a cdn:  https://s1-excel-15.cdn.office.net/x/s/1680161878__layouts/App_Scripts/Ewa.js

Comment: Is this in sharepoint online? On Prem?  If you try this on a file in OneDrive in Excel Online, does it fail there too?  (I.e., what does it take to repro?)

Comment: Issue appears in excel online only with the file stored in OneDrive.  I uploaded my manifest via the Insert tab -> Office Add-ins -> Mange My Add-ins.  Using Excel on mac, this does not happen.

Comment: The issue doesn't always happen.  Sometimes the error is not thrown, and the rest of the add-in code completes successfully.

Comment: Ok, let me see if someone can investigate.  Does it reproduce with a regular empty workbook, or might there be something special about your workbook?

Comment: Hi Michael - happy to share the file if we could get in touch.

Comment: Sure!  Please feel free to email me the file at <my first name><dot><last name><at><microsoft.com>